# Gregorian Date-numDays function

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have to write `numDays(otherdate)` function that returns the number of days as a positive integer between this date and the OtherDate.

This function belongs to class Date ADT that initialized to the given Gregorian Date. We have an Gregorian date in `self._date(month,day,year)` format. It must return difference between two dates.like 25 september and 6 october = it has 12 days difference

```
 def numDays(self,otherDate):
        print("Enter a date:")
        y=int(input("Year:"))
        m=int(input("Month:"))
        d=int(input("Day:"))
        today=self._date(y,m,d)
        diff=today-otherDate
        NoOfDays=diff.days
        print("The Number of day between today and Julian date is %s"%NoOfDays)
```

wrote like that but I know there are some mistakes.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I was just about to write something to this effect ... Do you keep this open in a text file that you can just copy/paste in here :-P

Comment: @mgilson: [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](http://stackapps.com/q/2116) for the win.

Comment: This is just the method, but you didn't tell us what problems you had. Nor do we know what `_date()` does, for example. If you have a traceback, include that in full.

Comment: what is the `otherdate` arguement?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you would also have to provide the country and for parts of europe even the state for which you calculate the difference.  See wiki at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar for details.

Although there is a general formula (which should be very easy to find), I don't think that this is accurate.

On the other side: Who cares. People who could have all passed away long time ago ;-)

Comment: otherdate is any date that should be given which we r gonna find  difference bw today and this date

Comment: @alzaimar: I think both date are assumed to be in a common Gregorian calendar for this problem.

Comment: No, as user1763124 stated above. But I know that there is a commonly accepted implementation that ignores my statement. I only wrote it to point that out.

Answer (score 0):

If both dates are `datetime.date` objects then to calculate number of days between today and the other date:

```
from datetime import date

number_of_days = date.today().toordinal() - other_date.toordinal()
```

It doesn't take into account timezone-related issues and it assumes that you wrote "Julian date" by mistake.

btw, there are 11 days between 25 Sep and 6 Oct:

```
>>> date(2012, 10, 6).toordinal() - date(2012, 9, 25).toordinal()
11
>>> date(2012, 9, 26).toordinal() - date(2012, 9, 25).toordinal()
1
>>> date(2012, 9, 25).toordinal() - date(2012, 9, 25).toordinal()
0
```

To do it without datetime module you need to perform some simple arithmetic. The calendar repeats itself every 400 years, see [the algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Gregorian_calendar).

Comment: OK its works but how to write it without datetime module.is there any way for this?

Comment: @user1763124: I've added the link to gregorian calendar algorithm